# Plotly Heatmap texttemplate not working with customdata

Tags: python, plotly, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to use custom data in the `texttemplate` of a `Heatmap` in Plotly, but it does not seem to work. I am using Python 3.10.12 and Plotly 5.15.0. Below there is a MWE:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import numpy

df = px.data.medals_wide(indexed=True)
fig = px.imshow(df)

customdata = numpy.zeros(df.shape)
fig.data[0].customdata = customdata
fig.data[0].hovertemplate = 'Custom data: %{customdata}' # This works fine.
fig.data[0].texttemplate = '%{customdata}' # This fails.

fig.write_html('deleteme.html',include_plotlyjs='cdn')
```

Produces:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

Comment: `customdata` is "_not user-visible but is included in events emitted by the figure_" (ie. hover, click, select, etc.), so you can use it in `hovertemplate` (hover event) or in Dash callbacks, but not directly as text. As mentioned by @r-beginners, what can be used for `texttemplate` is what you set for `text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't elaborate on why custom data is not supported, but the only thing that can be used for text templates is what you set for text, so set custom data for text.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy

df = px.data.medals_wide(indexed=True)
fig = px.imshow(df)

customdata = numpy.zeros(df.shape)

fig.data[0].customdata = customdata
fig.data[0].hovertemplate = 'Custom data: %{customdata}' 
fig.data[0].text = customdata
fig.data[0].texttemplate = '%{text}'

fig.write_html('deleteme.html',include_plotlyjs='cdn')
fig.show()
```

[image]